# jQuery data increment shorthand

Tags: jquery

Generally we can increment values by doing `i++` for any JS variable.

Can I do something similar to this jQuery code:

```
$this.data('numOfOccurrences', $this.data('numOfOccurrences') + 1 );
```

This doesn't work:

```
$this.data('numOfOccurrences')++;
```

Comment: `$this.data('numOfOccurrences')` is a node, not a local variable.

Comment: I really don't understand the down vote criteria here?

Comment: @karthikr, I understand, I'm asking for an increment shorthand for this type of nods/jQuery setter. If one exists :)

Comment: Likely voted down due to not reading the simple API... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: @buzzsawddog, sure I have & I know why ++ is not working, I just want to know if there is any tricks out there. Docs generally don't tell tricks & shorthands.

Comment: Have you tried it?   Mock it up.